# laptop is not able to access hotmail & Facebook

Tags: login, internet

I am having a strange problem with my laptop.I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on Dell Inspiron 1545.I use internet through wireless router.I have been using internet successfully without any kind of problem but now i am facing a weird problem.
The problems are:

1. My laptop is not opening Facebook.sometimes it opens login page but after entering usrname and passwd and clicking login.it just shows "connecting" message for a while then shows "Request time out" message.
2. Same problem is with hotmail except hotmail is always opening its login page.But nothing furthure.
3. The strangest problem is with youtube. I am able to see videos without logging in. But after login youtube shows a message "An error occured please try again latter".

And every browser on my laptop is showing same problem including firefox, Chrome, Chromium.

And i have windows 7 too on the same system. And i am not facing any problem on windows 7.

Comment: Can you enter the Facbook Mobile site? m.facebook.com, and drop Hotmail, use Outlook.com instead (better and improved version of Hotmail it is also set to replace it in the future).

Comment: Please try clearing your cookies and cache, especially if the sites you are entering are SSL-secured.

Comment: Thanks for quick replies.I tried both outlook.com and m.facebook.com .
None of them are opening.
I also cleared cookeis and cache, it also did not help...:(